# How to handle multiple rocket thrusters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm fairly new to game development and I'm trying to develop a 2D game in unity where the main character has a jetpack with two thrusters and I want him to control each one individually. So if he only turns on one thruster he goes 5 meters above ground and hovers there while using both would make him hover at a height of 10 meters. How would i go about doing this?

I tried just simply adding forces as if the character was jumping and freezing the y-axis to 0 until he let go of the jetpack button but that did not give me the feel i was looking for. I also tried raycasting a line out of the jetpacks to the closest surface and adding a force to the jetpack to allow the player to float at that height but that I couldn't figure out a proper way to implement it.

Comment: The most normal way to handle multiple forces is to add them together. But "the feel I was looking for", I'm guessing you want more realism. For instance, you mention this raycast to the closest surface, if you point a jetstream towards a wall, you will get more force than if you point it out into empty air, could this be a part of that "feel" you're missing?

Comment: It sounds like you were on the right track with the Raycast. What you would need to do is divide the force of your thrusters by the magnitude of the Ray. Thus, as the Ray gets longer, the force decreases. And as @LasseVågsætherKarlsen was saying, the jetpack force should just be added together. Thus, it's half as powerful with only one active, meaning that it would only go half as high.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Exactly, the character has the rockets attached to his arms, so if he pointed the thruster from one arm to the wall I'd want more force to push him away from it and eventually reach a state of equilibrium where he's just floating with the use of his thrusters.

Answer (score 0):

The Raycast sounds like a great idea. Do the raycast to the next available platform and do as @Ahndwoo said in a comment, `

> What you would need to do is divide the force of your thrusters by the
>   magnitude of the Ray. Thus, as the Ray gets longer, the force
>   decreases.

By doing this you'll get the natural movement from a force and you'll control how high can you get.

I would Make your thrusters holder as an object and as more turbines it has, the more powerful i'll get.